# It is correct calling a final property "variable" despite of being a constant?

Tags: java, final

I've seen a lot of people calling for example :

```
final String foo = "foo";
```

A "final variable" .

However , I completely disagree . When a type of data in Java has the final modifier , immediately I call it "Constant" . A variable cannot be a constant (completely illogical).

Am I wrong?

Comment: Generally when someting is a `static final` it is considered a constant. A `final` variable can be assigned once and this can be done in a constructor. This cannot be done with a `static final` as that has to be prepared upon loading the class.

Comment: Why does it matter? Your "problem" probably comes from the fact, that there could be multiple definitions of "variable". Read [this article on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)). "Variable" doesn't necessarily mean that the value has to change.

Comment: "Variable" as the name suggests , means something that CAN change , a final reference CANNOT change once you set a value to it , so there is nonsense calling a constant variable.

Comment: You may not be technically wrong but insisting on such a distinction could be considered pedantic. Even if you are correct I would suggest moving on and accepting the status quo; this is not something you're likely to change on your own.

Answer (score 5):

While in the industry we all use tend to mix the names, but generally speaking the difference between "final variable" and "constant" is that "constant" is known in compile time, while final variable is not.

Take a look at this example:

```
@Test
public void testMe() {
    class A {
        final String foo;
        A(int i) {
            foo = (i > 10) ? "foo" : "bar";
        }

        void print() {
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }

    A a1 = new A(20);
    A a2 = new A(5);
    a1.print();
    a2.print();

}
```

This code compiles and produces the following output:

```
foo
bar
```

So that's why technically it can be a called a final variable.

Even if you assign the value immediately:

```
final String foo2 = "foo2";
```

Its technically possible to write something like this (completely contrived I admit):

```
final String foo2 = SOME_VAR > 5 ? "foo2" : "bar2";
```